# What's the int macro for stdin?

Tags: c, macros, stdin

`stdin` is of type `FILE *`,

is there a `fd` macro for it?

Or do I need to convert it myself?

Comment: You could just "guess" that `stdin <==> 0`; `stdout <==> 1`; `stderr <==> 2`

Comment: There's no need to guess - POSIX requires that, so you could legitimately just use the numbers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`STDIN_FILENO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) from `unistd.h`

Answer (score 7):

[`fileno(stdin)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno)

Answer (score 2):

The following are the integer file descriptors for the standard streams:

- **0**: `stdin`
- **1**: `stdout`
- **2**: `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    
    char ch;
    read(STDIN_FILENO,&ch,1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,&ch,1);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```